# Laravel - whereHas query not returning correct records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I am currently writing a search query but I'm having issues joining a `where` with a `whereHas`

**if I wanna search for categories only..**

The below query works if I just search for categories solo

```
 $goals = $myGoals
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
        })->paginate(10);
```

**if I wanna search for the title only..**

Same as above if I wanna search for the title of goals solo

```
$goals = $myGoals->where('title', 'like', "%$search%" )->paginate(10);
```

both of the queries work if I want to search for them individually.

**Query attempt**

Below is the query I've written to allow a user to search for the `title` of a goal and the `name` of a `category`.

```
 $myGoals = $team->goals();

    $goals = $myGoals
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
        })->where('title', 'like', "%$search%" )->paginate(10);
```

I have tried the above query but the search results return empty when I enter an input. I've also tried swapping the `where()` to `orWhere()` which then returns a goal that doesn't belong to the `$team` model instance but it's a goal record linking to a different `Team` model `id` within the pivot table.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it all inside where.

```
$goals = $myGoals->where(function ($query) use ($search){
                return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($search) {
                    $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
                })->orWhere('title', 'like', "%$search%" );
                })->paginate(10);
```

Comment: that worked a charm! thanks dude. Can you explain why a where() is needed at the top?

Comment: Because orWhere() interferes with other conditions on the same level. That's why we moved it to another condition level. So that it only works with whereHas('categories') condition....

Comment: That makes sense, thankyou for the explanation